# How do I integrate AWS Amplify with Cognito into React-Native App?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm attempting to integrate AWS Amplify with Cognito into an existing React-Native application.

Here is the content of my aws-exports.js file.

```
const config = {
        identityPoolId: 'xxxxxxxx',
        region: 'xxxxx',
        userPoolId: 'xxxxx',
        userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxxx'
  }

export default config;
```

I am configuring amplify in my index.js file with the following:

```
import Amplify from '@aws-amplify/core';
import awsConfig from './src/aws-exports'

Amplify.configure(awsConfig);
```

And here is where I'm attempting to use the Auth method to sign up users etc:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

class AuthenticationService {
  confirmationResult: any
  phoneNumber: any

  signInWithPhoneNumber() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const strippedPhone = phone.replace(/\D/g, '')
       const formattedPhone = `+1${strippedPhone}`

     
        Auth.signUp({
        username: 'jello',
        password: 'jello',
        attributes: {
          phone_number: formattedPhone
        }
      })
        .then((confirmationResult:any) => {
          this.confirmationResult = confirmationResult
          resolve(null)
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          reject(error)
        })
    })
  }
```

I don't have any errors with what I have here, however I keep getting the following :

```
Unhandled JS Exception: Can't find variable: self
```

I've been searching for a while and I happened upon `"whatwg-fetch: 2.0.4"` However that didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer here, although a peculiar one. I was able to solve this by Enabling Remote Debugging on my iOS simulator. Not sure how the two are related, but this solved the issue.